# Webpack Encore access module in twig template

Tags: symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

i want to create a DOM related function that i will use in multiple templates of my project.
My function works when i write it in a template but when i place it in a dedicated file in my 'assets' folder, it doesn't work anymore.

submitForm.js

```
function submitForm(buttonId){
  setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById(buttonId).disabled = true;},1000);
  document.getElementById(buttonId).innerHTML = "Chargement";
  }
```

app.js

```
// form validation
import './submitForm';
```

webpack.config.js

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore

    .setOutputPath('public/build/')

    .setPublicPath('/build')

    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')
```

template.twig

```
{% block script %}

    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}

<script>
    ....
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you build the assets like it says in [this article](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html)?

Comment: Yes, it did not work

Comment: where is your script block? in the header or at bottom of the page? if its in the footer the call and the function itself should be wraped in some dom ready function.